# In WPF, how to I bind to a fraction of a property?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How do I bind something to a fraction of a Path value?  Path=ActualPath/2 does not seem to work.

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, 
                   Path=ActualHeight / 2}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using a ValueConverter, for example:

```cs
class MakeHalfConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value)/2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value)*2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. You need to use a value converter for this.
Have a look [here](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/) for several ready to use converters. You can use the [`ExpressionConverter`](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=User%20Documentation&referringTitle=Home#ExpressionConverter) for your scenario.